# How do I move all emails to another folder except the most recent

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to move all emails, except the most recent email, from one folder to another.

The code below moves all but one email but its not the last email received.

Do I have to refer to .ReceivedTime to give it a time reference?

```
For i = objstartFolder.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

    With objstartFolder.Items(2)

        On Error Resume Next

        .Move objMoveFolder

   End With
```

I tried

```
 For i = objstartFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
 For i = 1 To objstartFolder.Items.Count Step 1
 For i = 0 To objstartFolder.Items.Count -1 Step 1
```

Comment: Will there be other types of item in the folder? - not all items are necessarily mail items.  The order in which items are retrieved by `folder.Items` doesn't follow any chronological order, so you'll have to loop through all of the items, find the latest one, then move all the rest.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thanks, I was thinking that it mustn't run chronologically. Any ideas on how might write the loop you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting first then delete.

objstartFolder.Items.Sort "Received", False

For an example see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163981(v=office.10).aspx

Edit 2015 02 16

I originally sorted the items in the folder directly.
If it worked it would be unreliable as True / False was the same

```
Sub SortByReceived_Move()

    Dim myNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim myFolder As folder
    Dim myMoveToFolder As folder
    Dim myItems As Items
    Dim j As Long

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("@Play")
    Set myMoveToFolder = myFolder.Folders("@Test")

    Set myItems = myFolder.Items

    myItems.sort "Received", True
    Debug.Print myItems(1).Subject & " - " & myItems(1).ReceivedTime

    For j = myItems.count To 2 Step -1
        Debug.Print myItems(j).Subject & " - " & myItems(j).ReceivedTime
        myItems(j).Move myMoveToFolder
    Next j

ExitRoutine:
    Set myNameSpace = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing
    Set myMoveToFolder = Nothing
    Set myItems = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit 2015 02 16 end

Comment: This will not work as you are using multiple dot notation and the Items collection is sorted and immediately discarded. The next time you call MAPIFolder.Items, you will end up with a brand new COM object that has no knowledge of the previous objects.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use multiple dot notation, especially in a loop - each "." will return a brand new COM object. Cache the Items collection before sorting it and looping. You might also want to restrict (`Items.Restrict`) the collection first.

```
Items = objstartFolder.Items;
Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '2013-01-01' ");
Items.Sort("ReceivedTime");
for (int i=Items.Count; i >= 1; i--)<
{
    Item = Items.Item(i);
    ...
    Item.Move(SomeOtherfolder); 
}
```